# Usar selectpicker no jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho esse código de selectpicker(bootstrap)

```
<select name="nivel_p" class="selectpicker">
    <option>menor que 6</option>
    <option>7-15</option>
    <option>16-40</option>
    <option>maior que 40</option>
</select>
```

Eu preciso disparar um comando toda vez que a seleção do select for alterada,mas eu não faço a minima idéia de como faz pensei em algo como:

```
$('select[name=nivel_p]').selectpicker(function() {
}
```

Mas não funcionou,qual a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para "disparar um comando toda vez que a seleção do select for alterada" pode fazer usar o evento `change` e o código seria assim:

```
$('select[name=nivel_p]').on('change', function(){
    // correr código aqui
});
```

Exemplo:

```js
$('select[name=nivel_p]').on('change', function(){
    alert('A opção selecionada mudou!\nO novo valor é: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="nivel_p" class="selectpicker">
    <option>menor que 6</option>
    <option>7-15</option>
    <option>16-40</option>
    <option>maior que 40</option>
</select>
```